# Difficulty understanding proof regarding conservative vector fields

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, vector-fields

[image]

This theorem asserts that if a vector field is independent of path and is continuous on an open, connected domain, then the field is conservative.

I highlighted the part of the proof I am struggling with. I don't understand how the first integral regarding C1 is independent of x and can thus equals zero. How can this be true if there is a change of x from A to x1, what does it mean for x1 to be "constant?"

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When computing $\partial f/\partial x$, you're investigating how the value $f(x,y)$ changes as you move the point $(x,y)$ right/left along the horizontal line in the picture (i.e., you vary the value of $x$ while keeping $y$ constant). But the point $(x_1,y)$ doesn't move.

Comment: I'm just confused because C1 is defined as A to (x1, y) and it seems to there is a change of X when moving from A to x1?

Comment: But $(x,y)$ denotes the *endpoint* of the curve. If you need some symbols for the point that “moves along the curve” while you're integrating, you'll have to use some other letters, like $(\xi,\eta)$ for example. Then $\xi$ (not $x$) will change as you move from $A$ to $(x_1,y)$.

Comment: Maybe you would find it less confusing if you call the endpoint $(u,v)$ instead, so that $f(u,v)$ is the integral from $A$ to $(u,v)$, and then investigate $\partial f/\partial u$?

Comment: So just to reiterate, the first integral is independent of x because that point, (x1,y) is does not change value in the domain due to path independence?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by “due to path independence” here.

Comment: Sorry, I mean when only final and initial points matter, but disregard this. So I understand what you mean by (x1, y) being a constant, I'm just still struggling to understand why that means the integral from A -> (x1,y) is ultimately zero and independent of x?

Comment: The integral over $C_1$ isn't zero, it's its **derivative** (with respect to $x$) that is zero. And the reason for why the derivative is zero is that the integral over $C_1$ is independent of $x$. And the reason for *that* is that when you move the point $(x,y)$ sideways, you're only changing the curve $C_2$; the curve $C_1$ is unchanged, and therefore so is the integral over $C_1$.

Comment: Ah, now I see, thank you for your patience!